# Invalid expression term '{' (Declaring array outside switch statement)

Tags: c#, arrays

I've started an algorithm for a program, and I've declared the array in method itself. However, when I reference the array inside the switch statement I get repetitive errors: Invalid expression term '{' and '{' expected and ';' expected
Below is the code:

```
algorithm()
{
code .....
int[] interval;
more code....
switch (int.parse(lbl2.text))
    {
    case 1:
        sInterval = {10, 20, 30, 40};
        break;
    case 2:
        sInterval = { 50, 60, 70, 80};
        break;
    }
}
```

How do you fix this problem?

Comment: The basic issue is that you are using the Java style of declaring an array, which is not valid C# syntax

Answer (score 9):

The correct syntax is `new int[]{10, 20, 30, 40}`

Comment: Alternatively you can leave out the `int` and just have `new[] {10,20,30,40}`. Since interval was already declared as an `int[]`.

Comment: @KevinWells A small nitpick: it's not because `interval` was defined as an `int[]`, it's because `10`, etc. are `int` literals.  C# doesn't look at the destination to deduce the type (except in the case of lambdas).  It first deduces the type and then checks that it's compatible for assignment.  If you wrote `new[] { 10.0 }` for example, this would result in a compile error that `double[]` can't be assigned to `int[]`.

Comment: Good point, thanks for the clarification, I had that totally backwards in my head

Answer (score 0):

Fábio's answer is correct. However it can be used to further improve your code:

```
var sIntervals = new Dictionary<int, int[]>()
{
    { 1, new[] { 10, 20, 30, 40} },
    { 2, new[] { 50, 60, 70, 80} },
    // you can easily add intervals here
};

// you can get interval simple like this
// var sInterval = sIntervals[1];
```

Next step is to replace `parse` with `tryparse`, to avoid exception there.